# NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: returning incorrect height on retina displays

Tags: iphone, iphone-4, sizewithfont

I think I have found an edge case for sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: where, on a retina display, it will sometimes (it seems based on word wrapping) returns a height 1 line taller than is actually needed, and more importantly than is it actually draws.

NOTE: The real code I am using is buried inside performant centric hand drawn variable height table view cell code, so I've distilled the issue down to as simple a bit of sample code as possible. (Please take note of this when trying to answer something other than my question  :-)

This sample UIView fills it's content, measures the text to fit (wrapped), fills that rect, then draws the text.

On a retina device (or simulator) the height is returned 1 line too tall, but on a pre-retina device (or simulator) it returns the correct height.

I would greatly appreciate any insight anyone may have, as it is a bug i'd like to fix!

Much Thanks!

-eric

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 NSString * theString = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit ameyyet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vel justo leo. Curabitur porta, elit vel.";
 UIFont * theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
 CGSize theConstraint = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width - 20, rect.size.height - 20);
 CGSize theResultSize = [theString sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:theConstraint];

 // dump the measurements
 NSLog(@"returned a size h = %f, w = %f", theResultSize.height, theResultSize.width);

 // fill the whole rect
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [[UIColor yellowColor] set];
 CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

 // fill the measured rect
 CGRect theRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, theResultSize.width, theResultSize.height);
 context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 [[UIColor cyanColor] set];
 CGContextFillRect(context, theRect);

 // draw the text
 [[UIColor blackColor] set];
 [theString drawInRect:theRect withFont:theFont];
}
```

The whole simple project is available [here](http://d.pr/Cm5P).

Simulator Images:
http://files.droplr.com/files/9979822/aLDJ.Screen%20shot%202011-01-11%20at%2012%3A34%3A34.png
http://files.droplr.com/files/9979822/YpCM.Screen%20shot%202011-01-11%20at%2012%3A36%3A47.png

Comment: Tough one, right?  Can someone help?  The Tumbleweed badge was not super fun to earn!

Comment: After runing your sample project, I believe it was a simulator or SDK's bug, yes, it has no problem on the Xcode 4 with iOS 4.3.

Comment: Thanks xan. It is now functioning as it should in the current Xcode/iOS

Comment: Well.. I just had this same bug show itself in iOS8... Time to start paying attention to it again. This time it is happening ON DEVICE!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with your simulator. This is what I got when I ran it with a Retina simulator on OS 4.3.2

[image]

Comment: Thanks for looking at it. I'll have to fire this up, and see if it's still doing that on the current OS(s).

Comment: You are correct, it's fixed in the new OS/Xcode. +1 for actually running my sample vs. telling me how to measure text  ;-)  thanks Sum!

Comment: Well.. I just had this same bug show itself in iOS8...  Time to start paying attention to it again. This time it is happening ON DEVICE!!

Answer (score 1):

Following is the method I use to find the height of label for dynamic text content. This works fine in my app

```
- (float)getHeightFortheDynamicLabel:(NSString *)stringForTheLabel
{
    UITextView *aSampleTextView;
    // 30 is the minimum height
    aSampleTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mywidth, 30)];
    aSampleTextView.text = stringForTheLabel;
    aSampleTextView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kMyFontSize];
    aSampleTextView.alpha = 0;
    [self.view addSubview:aSampleTextView];
    float textViewHeight = aSampleTextView.contentSize.height;
    [aSampleTextView removeFromSuperview];
    [aSampleTextView release];
    return  textViewHeight;

}
```

Comment: Interesting idea...  expensive as it is... I'll have to take a fresh look...  a year later...  :-)

Comment: Before using this method, I just tried (CGSize theResultSize = [theString sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:theConstraint];
) But it was not that much accurate(I don't know why).  Even though this method consumes little etc memory usage, It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
        NSString *strSubstring = @"asdfghjklasdfghjkl adsds";

        CGFloat maxWidth = 205.0;
        CGFloat maxHeight = 9999;
        CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(maxWidth,maxHeight);
        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [strSubstring sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"StagSans-Light" size:12] constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        NSLog(@"returned a size h = %f, w = %f", expectedLabelSize.height, expectedLabelSize.width);

        return expectedLabelSize;
```